# How to draw a reverse Z shaped figure using View in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I need to draw a reverse Z shaped figure like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMFRu.png) in Android using View element. I can't use any image. I need to achieve it using View.

Explanaton of the attached image :

1. The rectangle box represents the screen of the mobile device.
2. The reverse Z shaped figure is what I need to draw using View; such that the center of the slanting line ("/") should coincide with the center of the device screen. The other two lines should be of same length as well.
3. The figure should be relative to the screen sizes.

Thanks!

Comment: No updates still? :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom `View` (a class that extends `View`)
2. Call `setWillNotDraw(false)` in its constructor (to make sure your custom `onDraw` will be called)
3. Create custom `onLayout` method in which you will calculate positions of those four points (store them as fields of your custom `View`):

[image: four points]

4. Create custom `onDraw` method in which you will use various `Canvas` methods to draw your things.

   - Frame: use [`drawRect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRect(android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint)) with `Paint` object that has `stroke`
   - "The reverse Z shaped": there many ways to draw this thing e.g. use [`drawLines`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLines(float[],%20android.graphics.Paint)) to draw lines between points calculated in 3.